# Photovoltaic cell used in calculators

Tags: solar-cell

I wish to make a PV powered (and battery backed) LCD clock.
From what I understand my requirement may be served by a PV (photovoltaic) cell that provides similar or superior functionality to those found in solar powered calculators.

An example of the sort of PV cell that I am referring to is shown in the photo below.

I would be obliged if people could advise me re how to specify a PV cell that would be liable to meet my needs.

I know how to shop and do not need any instruction in this art   - but I do not know the sort of suppliers that may sell what I need or how to tell them what I need. Can anyone advise me in this matter without violating site protocols so that I can turn my new-found technical knowledge into a real world product.

[image: calculator]

Comment: And yes, I did search for the spec sheet for CASIO fx-991 ES, but couldn't find it

Comment: Ahem .. where did I ask for "recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them" ??? I just asked some pointers on good PV cells.

Comment: "*What is the model number of the photovoltaic cell [...]*"  "*I just asked some pointers on good PV cells.*"  That's seeking recommendations for products.  No hard feelings.

Comment: is this something related to competitions of [techfest](http://www.techfest.org/)?

Comment: Second hand stores may have the solar patio/driveway/garden lights. They will have a battery/solar cell match that may save on designing.

Comment: The question has been edited so that the clear and valid technical question previously posed by the OP is  even clearer. Please reopen the question so that people can answer it.

Comment: Note that the PV cell they use in calculators rates in the milliwatts, and the ICs even less.

Comment: PV cells in calculators are often low performance. A crystalline silicon pv panel can be bought from many general purpose electronic product suppliers. Output in full sun is typically about 5 to 15 mW/cm^2. Full sun is about 100,000 lux and indoor light in well lit  room is perhaps 100-500 lux so levels are 0.1% - 0.5% of full sunlight. PV output falls with light level with essentially constant V and decreasing V down to about 1000 lux and V & I fall below about there. At 100 lux you would be lucky to get 5 to 50 microwatt per cm^2. In full sun V out is typically about 0.55V/cell ....

Comment: .... and falls to say 50-70% of this by 1000 lux and trends down somewhere below there. The calculator PV unit in your example would be lucky to give 10's of uW.

Comment: To Russell ... thanks for the edit :-)     To Jigar ... no its my own hobby project and nothing to do with techfest

Comment: um ... yes I searched the net and I guess the current at 5V and 200 lux is in few tens of uA, so at best its good for a LCD 7 segment display, a frequency divider and a crystal oscillator ckt ...:-( .... does anybody have an idea how does a calculator work indoors away from direct sunlight at so low a current? I mean even a microcontroller will take about 10mA..won't it?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the spec sheet on that model calculator, but [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-0-8W-160mA-Mini-Solar-Panel-Module-DIY-for-Cell-Charger-/351108888512?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item51bfb877c0) is a solar cell I've used for a project. It's fairly cheap on eBay, and I'm assuming your LCD clock won't need any more than 5V.

But there are thousands of solar cells online, just Google them.

Comment: Thanks! Does a typical mini-solar panel work indoors (e.g. the one you used in your project), away from direct sunlight? I am talking of typically 25-30 mA of current at 5V?

Comment: @user3211857  (1) Hand-waving towards eBay and Google and saying there are "thousands of them out there" does not constitute a good answer on EE.SE .  (2) An eBay auction doesn't make a good reference.  The auction expires sooner rather than later, and link dies.

Comment: None of them work well indoors, including the calculator one. You may need a couple of square feet to get 10s of mA indoors, unless by "indoors" you mean sitting in a sunny window.

Comment: True. I didn't consider you'd be using it indoors. Most of the ones you see online are suited better for outdoor use.

Comment: Any idea how do calculators make use of the PV cells indoors? I mean the current required for any microcontroller has to be a few tens of mA??

Comment: The solar cells found in calculators and most other small devices requiring power are most likely amorphous solar cells. They aren't as efficient as crystalline solar cells, which are found in the deserts, on rooftops, in large scale operations. But this has been greatly improved over the years. Amorphous solar cells have the advantage of having a cheaper price per watt of power generated when compared to crystalline ones.

Comment: You can use a solar-powered calculator because its duty cycle is low. That is, it spends much more time charging and storing power than being used. Clocks, on the other hand, have to run continuously. While the timekeeping circuitry can be made very thrifty, it's still difficult, and in general a clock needs to be visible at all times, so the much more power-hungry display will also run. I once had an early LED watch (the Pulsar), and you had to hit a button for the display to come on for a few seconds. It was very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a Dollar Tree store and get a solar powered LED yard path light- You'll get a nice package that comes apart easily, with a 1.5V 30mm square solar panel, a battery holder with a rechargeable Ni-cd AAA battery, and a small circuit board with a transistor (mosfet) that switches the onboard LED on when there's little light, and switches back to charge mode when there is light. For a clock with an LCD display, I believe regular inside light would probably power it, but you would need a backup battery to get through the night.